# Modify JSON values based on array of keys using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to change the value of a set of keys (defined in a variable) in a JSON object using jq.

As example, I have this JSON object:

```
{
    foo: {
        bar: 1,
        baz: 2,
        qux: 3
    }
}
```

and the following variable:

```
update_keys = ["bar", "baz"]
```

I would like to say 'change the value of the keys in update_keys to X'.

The following works:

```
.foo = (.foo | 
        to_entries | 
        map(if .key == "bar" or .key == "baz" 
        then . + { "value":"X" } 
        else . 
        end) |
        from_entries)
```

But instead of `if .key == "bar" or .key == "baz"` I am looking for a way to say `if .key in update_keys`, or a similar logic.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the outcome should be. Not sure if you want to extend update_keys or modify .foo

Comment: I want to update foo, changing the values of the keys defined in the update_keys array (all keys change to the same value)

Comment: Is `update_keys` already a variable that you've defined in `jq`?

Comment: @TomFenech no, I am very new to jq.. did not know we could have variables

Comment: Never knew of this tool. Thanks a buch for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

**Filter**

```
.foo |= with_entries( .value = if ([.key] | inside(["bar", "baz"])) then "X" else .value end )
```

**Input**

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": 1,
        "baz": 2,
        "qux": 3
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "X",
    "baz": "X",
    "qux": 3
  }
}
```

Check out the cookbook for more recipies and techniques of `jq` usage:
  https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach using `--argjson` to parameterize update_keys, and `index/1`:

```
$ cat update.jq
.foo |= with_entries( . as $in 
          | if $update_keys | index($in.key) then .value = "X" else empty end)

$ update_keys='["bar", "baz"]'

$ jq --argjson update_keys "$update_keys" -f update.jq input.json

Output:

{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "X",
    "baz": "X"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this problem since `$update_keys` is just an array all that is needed is

```
 .foo[ $update_keys[] ] = "X"
```

e.g. if

```
  ["bar","baz"] as $update_keys
| .foo[ $update_keys[] ] = "X"
```

is in `filter.jq` and `data.json` contains the (slighty corrected) data

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 1,
    "baz": 2,
    "qux": 3
  }
}
```

then

```
jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "X",
    "baz": "X",
    "qux": 3
  }
}
```

If you want to pass in the value for update keys instead of defining it in your script you can easily use `--argjson` as [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s answer shows.